# awk - fatal error while reading file

Tags: shell, unix

I am stuck with below issue related to `awk` command.

As per below function, Input-command produces 5 csv files & dump them into respective csvFolder. Issue is when function is called it is throwing below error as `awk` does not get value of `$I`.

> awk: fatal: .... reading (No such file or directory)

Is there any way to bypass this awk condition if csv files are not there in csvFolder or csvFolder2?

```
Function() {

#CSV prducer command

Input-command="$command-to-calculate"

#Parse csv files to get row count which do not have special-word

for I in csvFolder/*.csv
Do
   Var=$(awk 'NR>1' csvFolder/$I | grep -cv 'special-word')
   Echo $Var
Done 

#CSV prducer command no. 2

Input-command-2="$command-to-calculate" 

#Parse csv files to get row count which do not have special-word

for I in csvFolder2/*.csv
Do 
   Var=$(awk 'NR>1' csvFolder2/$I | grep -cv 'special-word')
   Echo $Var
Done 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current for loop ie :

```
for I in csvFolder/*.csv
```

`I` will have values like `csvFolder/sample.csv`. So you need not do

```
Var=$(awk 'NR>1' csvFolder/$I | grep -cv 'special-word')
```

Instead do

```
Var=$(awk 'NR>1' "$I" | grep -cv 'special-word')
```

Moreover, grep is redundant here. If you're trying to count the lines that doesn't contain 'special-word`, You could do it like :

```
Var=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}!/special-word/{if(NR>1){count++}}END{print count}' "$I")
```

---

**Side note:**

Shells are case sensitive, `Echo $Var` should have been `echo $Var` and so on.

Comment: With second case where are we passing csv file?

Comment: I tried this code offline but $var getting string instead of count actually

Comment: Worked above code. And I want to exclude header as well. Know only NR>1?

Comment: In csv file first line will be header. How we can ignore header using above code?

Comment: NR>1 and curly braces with above condition throws syntax error. Can you please write full length code so I will try that. And thanks sjsam 

Comment: @Rock : Updated.. and please delete the irrelevant comments.

Comment: Also it should return 0 count if there are no match found but return blank

Comment: Also even if I provide $I argument to awk, if it doesn't have any value in csvFolder it still hangs execution